# Learning Git Best Practices

Tags: git

I like to practice Git in my local computer, what's the best way to do so.
I thought of creating two windows user accounts, two repositories(one for each user),
and mimic remote repository - all in my local computer.

I don't have a local network, but I do have access to internet.
I am particularly interested in resolving pull conflicts, working in
multiple branches, etc.

Please share your thoughts and experiences on the best way to learn Git.

Comment: Use bitbucket as a remote repository, it's free. Then you can have two copies of it on your machine...

Comment: best way to learn is sometimes just rtfm, but for sure not asking such questions on forums.

Comment: git cannot be practiced

Comment: OMG.. feeling bad.. with all the vote down his reputation is killed :/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have this in my `.bash_aliases` file:

```
alias gitlearn='cd; rm -rf gitlearn; mkdir gitlearn; cd gitlearn; git init; git commit --allow-empty -m"Add empty, initial commit"'
```

Any time I want to explore or practice with git, I just type `gitlearn`, and I'm in `~/gitlearn/` with a fresh repo, and a first empty commit, which makes it possible to rebase your first actual commit, as you need to specify the commit before the first commit you want to move when rebasing.

Then I just use a bunch linux commands to quickly make whatever setup I need. I've tested branching and merging strategies, interleaving the commits (respecting dates) of wholly-separate, unrelated repos in a new, common 3rd repo, test branch concepts, explored what happens with `git log --graph` output with really crazy merges, let myself get familiar with commands (like the dreaded `filter-branch`) on temporary clones, and even figured out what is actually required (which you can hand create yourself) to have a valid git repo.

Starting out in an empty directory:

```
~/gitlearn$ ls .git
ls: cannot access .git: No such file or directory
~/gitlearn$ git st
fatal: Not a git repository (or any parent up to mount point /home/gfixler)
Stopping at filesystem boundary (GIT_DISCOVERY_ACROSS_FILESYSTEM not set).
```

This is all you need to make a git repo:

```
~/gitlearn$ mkdir -p .git/objects .git/refs
~/gitlearn$ echo 'ref: refs/heads/master' >.git/HEAD
~/gitlearn$ git st
# On branch master
#
# Initial commit
#
~/gitlearn$ tree .git
.git
|-- HEAD
|-- objects
`-- refs

2 directories, 1 file
```

I'll do things like this:

```
~/gitlearn$ echo something >afile
~/gitlearn$ git add afile
~/gitlearn$ git st
# On branch master
# Changes to be committed:
#   (use "git reset HEAD <file>..." to unstage)
#
#   new file:   afile
#
~/gitlearn$ git commit -m'Add something to afile'
[master 3f78112] Add something to afile
1 file changed, 1 insertion(+)
create mode 100644 afile
~/gitlearn$ echo another thing >>afile
~/gitlearn$ git diff
diff --git a/afile b/afile
index deba01f..fa8eba8 100644
--- a/afile
+++ b/afile
@@ -1 +1,2 @@
something
+another thing
~/gitlearn$ git add --update .
~/gitlearn$ git commit -m'Add another thing to afile'
[master 5c639d9] Add another thing to afile
1 file changed, 1 insertion(+)
~/gitlearn$ git checkout -b feature
Switched to a new branch 'feature'
~/gitlearn$ echo >>afile
~/gitlearn$ echo feature 1 >>afile
~/gitlearn$ git diff
diff --git a/afile b/afile
index fa8eba8..be87597 100644
--- a/afile
+++ b/afile
@@ -1,2 +1,4 @@
something
another thing
+
+feature 1
~/gitlearn$ git add --update .
~/gitlearn$ git ci -m'Add feature 1 to afile'
[feature 25b20ab] Add feature 1 to afile
1 file changed, 2 insertions(+)
~/gitlearn$ git log --all --graph --decorate --oneline
* 25b20ab (HEAD, feature) Add feature 1 to afile
* 5c639d9 (master) Add another thing to afile
* 3f78112 Add something to afile
* 70e28a0 Add empty, initial commit
~/gitlearn$
```

etc... until I understand a concept. It's such a fast way to experiment. I use many aliases, too, which speeds it up even more, and, for example, with `git add --update .` I'll just type `git add --u<TAB> .`, so most commands tend to be fewer than 15 key presses.

I've recommended this to several people now. It's been a really great way to rapidly get myself acclimated to first the basics, and more recently the deeper internals of git.

As for remotes, I mimic those all the time locally. `mkdir remote.git; cd remote.git; git init --bare; cd ..; git clone remote.git local; cd local` and now you're in a 'local' repo that thinks of the one in 'remote.git' as its origin. There's no difference here from typical setups, save that the bare, 'remote.git' is actually on your local disc. From within 'local' you can push, fetch, and pull to and from 'remote.git', and it'll be functionally the same as what you'd do between a local and an physically remote repo.

Comment: Gary, you've given very useful commands, particularly having remote and local in the same machine. Would you please explain if it is possible to push changes to the remote(what setup locally) as two different users, if it is possible, then how can we do that? Do we need to configure those users in the respective .git/config file?

Comment: Yes. Example: `mkdir central; cd central; git init; git commit --allow-empty -m'Add initial, empty commit'; cd ..; git clone --bare central; rm -rf central; git clone central.git user1; git clone central.git user2; cd user1; git config --local user.name user1; git config --local user.email user1@company; cd ../user2; git config --local user.name user2; git config --local user.email user2@company; cd ..`, then you can work in `user1/` and `user2/` as separate users, each pushing and pulling to their sibling `central.git` repo. Those `git config --local` lines edit each `.git/config` for you.

Answer (score 4):

You can create a first repository on you filesystem (let's say you call it `origin`) and run inside :

```
git init --bare
```

Then you can do a first clone with :

```
git clone origin clone1
```

And a second :

```
git clone origin clone2
```

You can then commit, push and pull in each clones to train.